# IFTTT JavaScript filter - How to make case insensitive searches + How to search Include and Exclude sets of terms

Tags: filter, case-insensitive, ifttt

*First off I'm a total novice for Javascript, so please go gently.* *I'm aware of how people feel about having to now pay for IFTTT, but it's perfect for what I need.*

I am using a more expansive version of this code below to capture certain keywords from Tweets to then generate emails if the search returns a positive result.  This search works very nicely, except it is case sensitive which is a problem.

Yes, I know you can manipulate the twitter search to pick up specific words or phrases.  I am very proficient in achieving searches this way.  I am casting a wide net to pick up approx 120 search words or phrases which is too long to achieve through "OR" Twitter search parameters alone which is why I'm using this.

**Q1 -** I have tried adding `item.toLowerCase()` and just `.toLowerCase()` in various parts of the code so it wouldn't matter if the sentence case of the search term is different to that of the original tweet text case.  I just can't get it to work though.  I've seen various posts on here but I can't get any of them to work in IFTTT.  I believe IFTTT doesn't accept REGEX either, which is annoying.

Any advice of how to get this code running so it's case-insensitive for text within IFTTT?

**Q2 -** I have approx 120 search terms for the tweet text to return positive results.  There is a lot of junk that comes through with that. Does anyone know how to add a second layer of 'and exclude' search terms?

I have something like 300-400 words and specific phrases which would be used to stop the email from being triggered - so it'd be something like "*IF tweet text contains a, b, c BUT text ALSO contains x, y, z... do not send the email*"

```
let str=Twitter.newTweetFromSearch.Text;
let searchTerms=[
  "Northbound",
  "Westbound",
  "Southbound",
  "Eastbound"
]
let foundOne=0;
if(searchTerms.some(function(v){return str.indexOf(v)>=0;})){
  foundOne=1;
}
if(foundOne==0){
  Email.sendMeEmail.skip();
}
```

I have looked at the Twitter API, but that is a step too far for my coding ability which is why I'm using IFTTT.

Any help is very much appreciated
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm playing with IFTTT Filter myself at the moment, so here are some thoughts about solving your solution.

If you want to do a case insensitive seatch on the original text, convert the original text to lowercase, then have all your search terms in lowercase.

Plus I think you want to iterate over the searchTerms array, and use the `includes()` method. Ok, just realised that `.some()` does the iteration for you, but I prefer `includes()` over `indexof()`.

```
let str=Twitter.newTweetFromSearch.Text.toLowerCase();
let searchTerms=[
  "northbound",
  "westbound",
  "southbound",
  "eastbound"
]
let foundOne=0;
if(searchTerms.some(function(term){return str.includes(term);})){
  foundOne=1;
}
if(foundOne==0){
  Email.sendMeEmail.skip();
}
```

Or you could just skip having the `foundOne` variable, and do the search in the `if()` statement.

```
let str=Twitter.newTweetFromSearch.Text.toLowerCase();
let searchTerms=[
  "northbound",
  "westbound",
  "southbound",
  "eastbound"
]
if(!searchTerms.some(function(term){return str.includes(term);})){
  Email.sendMeEmail.skip();
}
```

Comment: I had been tinkering with the wrong thing!  Amazing, thank you. 

IFTTT doesn't seem to like the 'includes' from ```{return str.includes(term);})){``` so i have gone with
 
```let str=Twitter.newTweetFromSearch.Text.toLowerCase();
let searchTerms=[
  "northbound",
  "westbound",
  "blah",
  "blahdeeblah"
]
let foundOne=0;
if(searchTerms.some(function(v){return str.indexOf(v)>=0;})){
  foundOne=1;
}
if(foundOne==0){
  Email.sendMeEmail.skip();
}```

which is working a charm. 

Now I just need to figure out how to have Include serchterms ABC but skip of contains XYZ terms.

Comment: @RhysClayton If you have an include list and an exclude list, just have 2 lists of search terms, and nested IF statements. One to check for items and mark ok if found, and the second to check for items to reject for.
For efficency, you might want to put the list that occurs most often as the outer IF statement.
BTW, you can upvote answers that you think are useful. :)